# How many inversions in a permutation contain a fixed point?

Tags: permutations, proof-explanation, expected-value, permutation-cycles, fixed-points

An inversion occurs in permutation $X$ when $i < j$ and $X_i > X_j$, or when $i > j$ and $X_i < X_j$. A fixed point occurs when $X_i = i$, i.e., it is a cycle of length 1. If the pair $(X_i, X_j)$ is an inversion, obviously at most one of the two can be a fixed point.

I have found that, for $n = 4$, if a permutation of length $n$ contains any inversions, then the majority of inverted pairs contains no fixed points. In other words, for any of the $n!$ permutations of length $n = 4$, the probability of picking an inversion at random in that permutation, and finding that either $X_i$ or $X_j$ is a fixed point, is $P < .5$.

I would like to show whether this holds for larger $n$. Does a proof (or disproof) exist with respect to the proportion of inversions that contain fixed points? Or can someone guide me to how one would prove (disprove) it? Thanks!

Edit: I found a counterexample at $n = 5$: $(1,5,3,4,2)$. The fixed points are {$1,3,4$}, and the inversions are {$(5,3),(5,4),(5,2),(3,2),(4,2)$}. So $4/5$ of inversions contain a fixed point. I'm still interested in any theorems that exist related to this question.

Comment: Right, most will contain inversions, but the question is what proportion of inversions will include a fixed point. See the counterexample in my edit above. The given permutation has 5 inversions, of which .8 include a fixed point. Does that clarify?

Comment: I have deleted my previous comment.  I misunderstood your posting.  I thought that you were focusing on fixed points in the entire permutation.  Instead, you are only focusing on fixed points within the ordered pair (x,y) when this ordered pair represents an inversion.  ...My mistake.

Comment: That's correct, and I've edited to be more clear. Basically, I'm looking for the size of the intersection of the set of fixed points in X, and the set of pairs in X that are inversions.

Comment: For $n=4$ the permutation $(4,2,3,1)$ is essentially the same as your counterexample, with four of the five inversions containing a fixed point.

Comment: For additional context, it aids a separate proof if I can show the expected number of fixed points in a permutation Y, drawn randomly but not necessarily uniformly from the set of all n!, is monotone decreasing in the expected number of inversions. I suspect this follows from Mallows models of random permutations, which model Y from a nonuniform distribution of permutations, with expectation of permutation X and spread defined in terms of Kendall's tau distance. The conjecture above, while naive, would've been a lovely shortcut!

Comment: @DanielMathias Both are of the form (1,2,...,n-4,n,n-2,n-1,n-3), where your example is the special case where the first digit is 0, and all permutations of this form will have more inversions with fixed points than not.

Comment: I was thinking $(n,2,3,\cdots,n-2,n-1,1)$ and $(1,n,3,4,\cdots,n-2,n-1,2)$. The general form is a permutation with $n-2$ fixed points. All such permutations have exactly one inversion without a fixed point. If the swapped elements are not adjacent, there will be $2k$ inversions with a fixed point.